# Верстка сайта на основе готового дизайна

Tags: html, css

Я прочитал учебник по html/css, выполнил все упражнения в учебнике. Хочу закрепить знания на практике и сам попробовать сверстать пару сайтов используя html/css. Как мне на основе готового дизайна сверстать сайт?

Answer (score 3):

Разбиваете на блоки картинку, выделяете блоки со смещением. Потом просите дизайнера по разбивке нарезать картинок, либо режете сами.
Спрашиваете что является резиновым, а что статичным(чаще всего дизайнеру пофиг: он рисует одну картинку под определенное разрешение, так что вопрос актуален в большинстве случаев).
Совмещаете придуманные вами блоки с присланными картинками при помощи знаний, полученных из книжки.
Если с такой работой справляетесь за несколько часов(беловик), а за первые 30-40 минут можете накидать черновик - кусок хлеба с маслицем у вас всегда будет.
Отдельные плюсы:

- точность до пикселя
- кроссбраузерность
- соответствие W3C(для педантов)
- Использование элементов по-назначению: не надо использовать див со стилем, если можно использовать hX.